# Reason for the behavior of the reluctunt quantifier ?? in java regex

Tags: java, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

I know that the `?` is a greedy quantifier and `??` is the reluctant one for it.
When I use it as follows it gives me an empty output always? Is it because of it always operates from left to right (first looking at the zero occurrence then the matched occurrence) or another one?

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a??");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("aba");
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.start()+"["+matcher.group()+"]"+matcher.end());
    }
```

Output :

```
0[]0
1[]1
2[]2
3[]3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex could be explained as follows: "try to match zero characters, and if that fails try to match one 'a' character".

Trying to match zero characters will always succeed, so there is really no purpose for a regex that only contains a single reluctant element.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the Java implementation but [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) states this for `??` :

> Makes the preceding item optional. Lazy, so *the optional item is excluded in the match if possible*. This construct is often excluded from documentation because of its limited use.

Thus you get 4 matches (3 character positions + the empty string at the ent) and the optional `a` is excluded from each of those.